# Should I use the <main> element?

Tags: html, program-entry-point

I've stumbled about the  element on w3schools but as far as caniuse.com told me, the element isn't supported by IE, Opera Mini and the UC Browser for Android.

Would I be better by going with a `<main>` element or should I stick with a `<div id="main">`?

Comment: If you don't want to support the browsers you've listed you can use it. Otherwise not. Not sure if that wasn't obvious yet.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> caniuse.com told me, the element isn't supported by IE, Opera Mini and the UC Browser for Android

That isn't what it says.

It says "Partial support" and:

> Partial support refers to missing the default styling, as technically the elements are considered "unknown". **This is easily taken care of by manually setting the default display value for each tag**

So if `main` has the appropriate semantics, then use it. Just make sure to explicitly set `display: block`.

If the browser doesn't expose the semantics of using `main` then it will have no semantics, which is the same as a `div`.

Comment: In general, aren't browsers supposed to ignore tags they don't support? You don't need to set explicit CSS to get it to be displayed.

Comment: @Barmar — No, they are supposed to insert them into the DOM without any noticeable styling. That means they default to `display: inline` which is a problem if you want to set margins and the like on it.

Answer (score 0):

From [the looks of it](https://caniuse.com/#search=main) I wouldn't worry about compatibility, unless you are trying to support IE 8 and below.. You can cover all your bases by using both `<main role="main">` per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

> The  element is widely supported. For Internet Explorer 11 and
>   below, it is suggested that an ARIA role of "main" be added to the
>    element to ensure it is accessible (screen readers like JAWS,
>   used in combination with older versions of Internet Explorer, will be
>   able to understand the semantic meaning of the  element once
>   this role attribute is included).